# Make an image out of a running instance in OpenStack diablo

Tags: openstack

I have launched an instance in OpenStack and modified it, and I would now like to save it as a new image. How do I do that?

I'm running the diablo release.

Answer (score 3):

You do this with the `nova image-create` command. Here's how it works.

### 1. Get the ID of your running instance

Use the `nova list` command to do this. In the following example, the ID field is 11.

```
$ nova list
+----+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| ID |    Name   | Status |                 Networks                |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 11 | Server 11 | ACTIVE | internal_0=172.16.0.10, 199.189.191.183 |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
```

### 2. Create the image

Think of a good name for your image. For example, if you want the image name to be ubuntu-oneiric-test, using ID 11, you would do:

```
$ nova image-create 11 ubuntu-oneiric-test
```

This command will return right away, and will kick off the creation in the background.

### 3. Check the progress of image creation

Use `nova image-list` to check progress. Initially, it should look like this:

```
$ nova image-list 
+----+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| ID |          Name         | Status |                Server                |
+----+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 1  | ttylinux-kernel       | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 2  | ttylinux-ramdisk      | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 3  | ttylinux              | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 4  | ubuntu-oneiric        | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 5  | loader-kernel         | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 6  | loader-ramdisk        | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 7  | ubuntu-lucid          | ACTIVE |                                      |
| 8  | ubuntu-oneiric-test   | SAVING | 61054983-e127-4f97-83e0-90b272e95378 |
+----+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

When it's done, the status should switch from SAVING to ACTIVE.